# Vue custom directive how to receive a function as params and the function will not auto exec

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do I receive a function with params in directive like vue v-on?

```
<div v-example="test(id)"></div>
```

and this script

```
methods: {
    test(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

the test function will auto exec, but v-on will not?

Comment: Doubt: Are you looking for a function with some preset arguments ? If test is a method under `methods` then you can easily call it in directive using v-bind. Also, can you share how you have declared your directive ?

Comment: @82Tuskers I think he may want to make a custom event directive, like this vue2-hammer has the same problem https://github.com/bsdfzzzy/vue2-hammer/issues/24

Answer (score 2):

You may also do the following:

```
<div v-example="test(id)"></div>
```

script:

```
directives: {
  'example': {
    bind(el, binding, vnode) {
      el.addEventListener(binding.arg, (e) => {
        if(binding.value instanceof Function) {
          binding.value();
        }
      })
    }
  } 
},
methods: {
  test(id) {
    let local_id = id;
    return () => {
       console.log(local_id);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to mimic the built-in v-on style, there's too many problems includes auto run.

Below is the most concise and simple solution I can think of.

**html**

```
<div v-example="function(){ test(id) }"></div>
```

or more concise

```
<div v-example="()=>test(id)"></div>
```

**js**

```
directives:{
  example: {
    bind(el, binding){
      binding.value()
    }
  }
},
methods: {
    test(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass a function and the parameters separately to your directive like demonstrated on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/67909/). Since passing the function like `test('something')` will cause it to be evaluated immediately.

Just replace the inserted hook with the one you need: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments

```
<div v-demo="{myFunction: test, param: 'something'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.
If your goal is to pass the directive a function pointer (so you can execute the function later on inside your directive), you should listen to what gonnavis said and use an arrow function.

What you tried to do will not work because when Vue will mount the component, it will bind the directive to the element (`<div>`) and create a binding object. This object contains a "value" function which is assigned to return the argument you passed to the directive. So, while the directive is being bound, it calculates the value you passed to it, and if it is a function invocation, it invokes the function immediately.

You can imagine that when the element with your directive is bound, the following line will run:

```
const binding = {
  value: YOUR_ARG
}
```

And, in your case, it will be translated to:

```
const binding = {
  value: test(id)
}
```

Which will calculate test(id) immediately.

It is all about functional programming.